# how do i compare dates to get the required values

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

**Question : filter the json array and get the following**
1: All entries with name "Sam".
2: All entries with date "dec 2019".

// json Data below.

```
var arr = [{
    "id":"27",
    "0":{
        "name":"Sam",
        "date":"2021-02-28"
    },
    "1":{
        "name":"Mark",
        "date":"2019-12-08"
    }
    },{
    "id":"30",
    "0":{
        "name":"Sam",
        "date":"2019-12-11"
    }
    }
]
```

// code :

```
function filter(){
    var filtered = [];
    for (let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
        filtered = [];
        for(let x in arr){
            if(typeof(arr[x] == "object")){
                for(let k in arr[x]){
                    filtered.push({name : arr[x][k].name,date:arr[x][k].date})
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return filtered
}

function main(){
    var filter_date = [];
    var filter_name = [];
    var arr1 = filter()
    for(let i in arr1){
        if(arr1[i].name == "Sam"){
            filter_name.push(arr1[i])
        }
```

*i need to compare the dates if the dates are matching with if statement without hardcoding them*

```
 if(arr1[i].date == "2019-12-11" || arr1[i].date == "2019-12-08"){
            filter_date.push(arr1[i])
        }
    }
    // arr1.filter(item =>{   
    //             console.log(item)
    //             })
    console.log("the values with name SAM = ",filter_name)
    console.log("the values with name date Dec = ",filter_date)
}
main()
```

Comment: for comparisons of values in JS, always use ===

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), [`Object.Values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return the desired result.

Inside the filter() call, we'll return true if name is Sam or the month is December.

We can modify the filter function as needed.

```js
const arr = [{ "id":"27", "0":{ "name":"Sam", "date":"2021-02-28" }, "1":{ "name":"Mark", "date":"2019-12-08" } },{ "id":"30", "0":{ "name":"Sam", "date":"2019-12-11" } } ]

// Change as required. Currently matches name === 'Sam' or month is December
const filterFunction = ({ name, date }) => {
    return (name === 'Sam') || (date + '').split('-')[1] === '12';
};

const result = arr.flatMap(Object.values).filter(filterFunction);
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```